# Is there any issue with qrcode.QRCode while generating QR code in bulk?

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code

I am trying to make QR encoder-decoder which can result in QR code image with the same size and it will be the overlay to another image at fix location.

when I was trying to generate QR code into bulk its appending information in previous QR code image. Now, the image is growing and not in the same size. I want to append QR code into target fix location.

```
import qrcode
import cv2, glob, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version = 2,
    error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
    box_size = 8,
    border = 4,
)
for data in range(1,10):   
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)  
    img = qr.make_image()   
    img.save(str(data)+'.jpg')
```

I am expecting 10 QR code image with the same size

Answer (score 1):

After exploring qrcode library, I found object which can help to reset qrcode initialization.

```
import qrcode
import cv2, glob, os
import numpy as np


qr = qrcode.QRCode(
    version = 2,
    error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_M,
    box_size = 8,
    border = 4,
)

for data in range(1,10):   
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)  
    img = qr.make_image()   
    img.save(str(data)+'.jpg')
    qr.clear()
```